# Script tags not evaluated when templateUrl used

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angular component that retrieves its template externally by using templateUrl. Scripts in the template aren't evaluating, yet those same scripts evaluate fine if I change the templateUrl to template and paste that same markup in.

Another thing I noticed is that it's only a problem when using ng-if on the component tag or an ancestor.

[See plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/r1JmBvEg1DwLH2UCk4u7?p=preview)

Markup:

```
<body>
    <include-view ng-if="true"></include-view>
    <br><br>
    <include-view2 ng-if="true"></include-view2>
</body>
```

The components:

```
myApp.component('includeView', {
  template: '<script type="text/javascript">' + 
              'console.log(\'This works\');' +
            '</script>' + 
            '<b>this view is included by includeView component</b>' 
});

// the markup in Page1.html is identical to the markup above, yet the script does not eval
myApp.component('includeView2', {
    templateUrl: 'Page1.html'
});
```

Edit: simplified code

Comment: replace `ng-if` to  `ng-show`, the scope changes (_some magic is involved, we are not allowed to talk about it outside of Hogwarts_)

Comment: @AlekseySolovey the template should not be retrieved unless it's necessary so ng-show isn't an option. I wondered if ng-if creating its own scope could be the culprit, but it doesn't explain why template works and templateUrl does not

Comment: I think it's because it works just like `ng-template` (you can make another component to test it), where it calls `$templateCache` and creates a cache object that will be rendered later but not executed

Comment: _in docs:_ "Note that child elements that contain `templateUrl` directives will not have been compiled and linked since they are waiting for their template to load asynchronously and their own compilation and linking has been  suspended until that occurs."

Comment: Saw that, not sure what to make of it. It's obviously still compiled after the template is retrieved yet the scripts aren't evaluated, as if it's compiling in an entirely different way